# Is there any efficient alternative to JFrame in Java?

Tags: java, performance, swing, awt, processing-efficiency

I am coding a game in Java and was wanting to export it to less powerful machines, I have worked out how to export it to other platforms, but when running on less powerful machines it heats them up quite a bit. I have done some checking of my code and found the problem to be when I call the JFrame object in this class:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Display {

    private JFrame frame;
    private Canvas canvas;

    private int screenWidth;
    private int screenHeight;

    public Display(int width, int height) {
        this.screenHeight = height;
        this.screenWidth = width;
        makeDisplay();
    }

    public void makeDisplay() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/GameIcon.png")));;

        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));
        canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));
        canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));
        canvas.setFocusable(false);

        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
    }

    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public Canvas getCanvas() {
        return canvas;
    }

}
```

When I remove the instance of JFrame in the class the performance is significantly improved. So my question is, how to make this code either more efficient or if there is a more efficient way of making a similar thing to JFrame be used in my code.

Comment: The code you posted does nothing. If you have a performance problem the issue will be with your game logic.

Comment: With JFrame remove, your application does not produce any visuals, is it right? No surprise for it to be faster.

Comment: That's true but I was thinking that there has got to be a more efficient method of creating a screen to draw to in Java, I have run the code with just game logic and it doesn't take up much processing power at all, so I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of handling graphics in Java.

Comment: @JacobInwald of cause there are Graphics2D, JavaFX, a bunch of OSS Java game engines. You need to do some research.

Comment: Anyway, *creating* the screen can't be the culprit (unless you're doing it for every frame :D). The first time you do it, a bunch of classes gets loaded, which takes some time; however, the problem is either with your game logic or with your drawing - neither of them you've shown us. Please add the relevant parts to the question and/or do some measurements.

Comment: Here is the GitHub repository: https://github.com/JacobInwald/BattleGame . I have solved this issue though by changing the library I used to make Graphics appear. Also I can't keep this GitHub repository public for long as this is my computer science A-level project so making it public might cause the exam board to fail me as someone might submit might work as their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have researched other methods of making graphics appear in Java efficiently and have concluded that JavaFX is the way to go. I have implemented it in my Main function and the code now utilises <3% of my CPU (I have an Intel Core i7 8th Gen) according to Task Manager. This is a drop of about 13 percentage points so I see this as a good step forward in making my code more efficient. As a quick note the KeyManager class just keeps the boolean values of which arrow keys have been pressed or not and the World class houses all the game logic. Here is the code that implements JavaFX:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import battlegame.graphics.Assets;
import battlegame.input.KeyboardController;
import battlegame.world.World;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.LongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleLongProperty;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Game extends Application{

    public static int screenWidth = 1248;
    public static int screenHeight = 624;

    private Canvas canvas;
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private Group group;
    private GraphicsContext g;
    private final LongProperty lastUpdateTime = new SimpleLongProperty(0);
    private static World currentWorld;
    private static KeyboardController keyController;

    public Game() {
        keyController = new KeyboardController();
    }

    public void begin(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void initialise() throws IOException {
        canvas = new Canvas(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        group = new Group(canvas);
        scene = new Scene(group);
        g = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        Assets.init();
        currentWorld = new World("/testlvl.txt");
        currentWorld.init();

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception {
        initialise();
        final AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long timestamp) {
                if (lastUpdateTime.get() > 16.6666666667) {
                    tick();
                    render();
                }
                lastUpdateTime.set(timestamp);
            }
        };
        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(Game.class.getResourceAsStream("/GameIcon.png")));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
            timer.stop();
        });
        stage.show();
        scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (key) -> {
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.W || key.getCode() == KeyCode.UP || key.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
                  keyController.up = true;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.A || key.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
                  keyController.left = true;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.S || key.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                  keyController.down = true;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.D || key.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                  keyController.right = true;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.Z || key.getCode() == KeyCode.O || key.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                  keyController.select = true;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.P || key.getCode() == KeyCode.X) {
                  keyController.action = true;
              }

        });

        scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, (key) -> {
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.W || key.getCode() == KeyCode.UP || key.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
                  keyController.up = true;
              }
        });

        scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, (key) -> {
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.W || key.getCode() == KeyCode.UP || key.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
                  keyController.up = false;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.A || key.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
                  keyController.left = false;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.S || key.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                  keyController.down = false;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.D || key.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                  keyController.right = false;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.Z || key.getCode() == KeyCode.O || key.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                  keyController.select = false;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.P || key.getCode() == KeyCode.X) {
                  keyController.action = false;
              }     });



        timer.start();   
    }


    public void tick() {
        keyController.tick();
        currentWorld.tick();

    }

    public void render() {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        currentWorld.render(g);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch();
    }

    public static KeyboardController getKeyController(){
        return keyController;
    }

    public static World getCurrentWorld() {
        return currentWorld;
    }



    }
```